# 'find' using regex with variables

Tags: regex, bash, find

Please, help me with the following:

Let it be three files:

```
file-aaa.sh 
file-bbb.sh
file-xxx.sh
```

In a bash script I have variables

```
$a=aaa 
$b=bbb
```

Now, I want to execute something like:

```
find . -name "file-[$a|$b].sh"
```

and expect to get two files in output.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this find:

```
find . -name "file-$a.sh" -o -name "file-$b.sh"
```

To combine it into one using `-regex` option:

**On OSX:**

```
find -E . -regex ".*file-($a|$b)\.txt"
```

**On Linux:**

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*file-($a|$b)\.txt"
```