# using shell variable in find regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, find

i would like to delete files with some pattern(like start with 'test')that older than 1 day, i have:

```
mydir=/find/my/path

find $mydir -type f -mtime -1\
-regextype egrep -regex '$mydir\/test.*'\
-delete
```

but it did not delete files for me, i tried

```
mydir=/find/my/path

    find $mydir -type f -mtime -1\
    -regextype egrep -regex '.*\/test.*'\
    -delete
```

this one works. Why did the first not work? according to
['find' using regex with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552144/find-using-regex-with-variables)
i can use variable in find regex, what's wrong?

Comment: What's the difference between single and double quotes in shell?

Comment: You also don't need regular expressions for that, btw. Just a normal file glob will do: `find "$mydir" -type -f -mtime -1 -name "test*" -delete`

Comment: @code3: In addition to the (correct) answer by gaganshera: Why are you using a regexp for such a simple case? `find $mydir -type f -mtime -1 -name 'test*' -delete` would do as well.

Comment: @Shawn and @user1934428 There is a subtle difference. Your commands would delete `mydir/dir/test` but not `mydir/testdir/file` whereas `-regex "$mydir/test.*"` deletes `mydir/testdir/file` but not `mydir/dir/test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in the 1st one, you tried to evaluate a variable `$mydir` inside a single inverted comma with `'$mydir\/test.*'`. This won't evaluate the `$mydir`'s value and will be taken literally as `$mydir`.

Use double inverted comma here and try again with

```sh
mydir=/find/my/path

find $mydir -type f -mtime -1\
-regextype egrep -regex "$mydir\/test.*"\
-delete
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gaganshera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61907255/6770384) already explains the the problems in your script and shows how to fix them. This is a different but equivalent solution combining `find` and globs:

```
mydir=/find/my/path
find "$mydir"/test* -type f -mtime -1 -delete
```